# Why do I need to install .NET Framework 3..5.1 updates though I don't have 3.5.1 installed?

Tags: windows-7, security, updates, hp-pavilion, .net-3.5

I have an HP Pavilion DV6 Laptop with an AMD 3510MX APU, running Win 7 Premium 64-bit.

Three security updates for Microsoft Framework ver. 3.5.1 appeared while updating Windows today, but don't think this version is installed and see just one update for this Framework; maybe a mistake on my part.

I *do* have Framework 4.0 installed, and will install these updates of course, but am curious about  offered updates for software that doesn't appear to be on my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows 7 comes with .NET 3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164495/windows-7-default-net-framework)

Look in c:\windows\Microsoft.net\framework - there should be a v3.5 folder.

Comment: This built-in version of .NET won't appear in the main add/remove programs list - you must click the "Turn Windows Features on or Off" link in the navigation pane.

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com/).
*Unsure how to answer, but thank you guys for making me feel like the Homer I am. lol Question answered, and can be closed. Really, thanks for the quick replies. Now I can get on with the updates. I feel like a dunce in here. lol take care all.*

Comment: @Tom Not at all sir. I do this for a living. And I had to go look it up myself. It's just not something I need to know on a daily basis. Nobody does. :) Also, I've done worse. Heck I've forgotten worse.